# freeglut OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':0'

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, opengl

I am trying to run an application with OpenGL and the following message apears:

```
freeglut OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':0'
```

I already read lots of topics here and in stackexchange and anyone of them presented a real solution; I am running an Ubuntu 12.04 with nvidia driver 346 (installed via file from site). The following informations are also pertinent:

glxinfo:

```
name of display: :0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

Xlog.0.log:

```
[    28.204] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    28.204] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    28.279] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules  /libglx.so: libnvidia-tls.so.304.125: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[    28.279] (II) UnloadModule: "glx"
[    28.279] (II) Unloading glx
[    28.279] (EE) Failed to load module "glx" (loader failed, 7)
```

lspci | grep VGA:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor   Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520M] (rev a1)
```